# Move Codeigniter's Model, View and controller folders outside Application

Tags: codeigniter

I would like to change/move the Model, View and Controllers folder from application folder and want them to be keep support in a new folder called app. Can someone please give me a solution which would work on CI-3*

application/
  library
  config
  helpers
  core
  ......

app/
  model
  views
  controllers

Comment: did you solve this, for example moving just "controllers" folder?

Answer (score 2):

`index.php` look for `$application_folder` and modify this.

You can move views separately using the `$view_folder` variable.

However, without changing the way the core of CI works you'd have to keep models/controllers inside of application.